# Can kopano handle multiple DB's for mailbox storage

Tags: email-server, truenas

I have a background in Exchange, but I am looking into a Kopano solution hosted on a freenas.
As i prefer ISCSI for the MySQL DB (for speed) and am noting the company growth which will be a lot in the future.

I wonder if kopano can handle multiple DB's. (so i could simply add ISCSI devices in the future).
In Exchange this would be a normal thing to do, but i'm not sure if kopano can handle this, or maybe we just then have to add another VM kopano 'brother' to handle the more mailboxes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the man page of [kopano-server.cfg](https://github.com/Kopano-dev/kopano-core/blob/master/installer/linux/server.cfg) only one MySQL/MariaDB per Kopano server node is possible. In a multi-server setup, you've obviously multiple Kopano server instances, but each instance still linked to one dedicated MySQL/MariaDB database.